# Is there any way through which we can limit the authentication in firebase to only one user

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to make a app which uses firebase authentication, storage and database but i want that only the admin can add the videos on the firebase means i want to limit the authentication to only the one person i.e. admin but the other users of the app can see the data i.e. videos on the app data is shared by the admin but users can not edit/ add the data to firebase.

E.g. the udemy app: where instructors can add the videos but students can only use that videos.

Note: I know how to allow the users to add the data by entering their information(email and password) but i want that there should be only one person who can enter the email and password to add the videos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot limit **authentication** to a specific user, but you can limit certain actions to that user.

For example, I often start my projects with security rules with a publicly readable database that only one account can write by embedding the UID for that one user into my rules. In Firebase Storage rules that'd look like:

> ```
> match /users/{userId}/profilePicture.png {
>   allow read;
>   allow write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == "theUidOfMyOneUser";
> }
> ```

At this stage anyone can call a sign-in API against my project and authentication, but only the user whose UID I have in my security rules is able to write files.

Also see the Firebase documentation on [securing access to files](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/), specifically the section on [giving users access to their own files](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/user-security#user_private) (which is what I based the above rules on).

Comment: Sir, @Frank van Puffelen thanks for your information but please tell me one more thing i.e. do i need to set/ assign any thing or value to userID or firebase will automatically detect the userID when someone sign in and what if someone is trying to create a new account which will be the first and the last account as i said only one user can write data in that condition our uid will automatically set or we have to set something on firebase and the last thing is in your answer you given the solution for images but i want for video so how can i do that thing also.

Comment: {
  /* Visit https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security to learn more about security rules. */
   "rules":{
     ".read":true,
     ".write":false,
   
       
      "posts":{
        "$uid":{
          
          ".write":"$uid === auth.uid",
        }
      }
   }
}This is what i had seen in a youtube video the same is the problem that do i need to assing something to uid?

Comment: @DishaNamdev Please limit the number of comments, and the amount of text in a comment, as it's hard to parse. To your additional questions: 1) the `request.auth` in security rules is automatically populated with the signed in user, and can't be spoofed. 2) the rules in your comment are for the Firebase Realtime Database, while your question is about Firebase Storage. While both support server-side security rules, their syntax is completely different. The equivalent to the snippet you show is in the second documentation link in my answer.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake sir@FrankvanPuffelen but please please can you provide me the exact firebase code for uploading videos on firebase for both realtime database and storage.Please earnest request.

Comment: I'd recommend starting from the samples in the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files. If you're having trouble getting that to work for you, post the [minimum, complete/standalone code that any of us can run to reproduce where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That gives you the best chance that someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class UploadVideo extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int PICK_VIDEO = 1;
    VideoView vidoeView;
    Button button;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    EditText editText;
    private Uri videoUri;
    MediaController mediaController;
    StorageReference storageReference;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    Member member;
    UploadTask uploadTask;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload_video);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        member = new Member();
        storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("Video");
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("video");




        vidoeView = findViewById(R.id.videoView_mainID);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button_upload_main);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBarID);
        editText = findViewById(R.id.et_video_name);
        mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        vidoeView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        vidoeView.start();

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                UploadVideo();
            }


        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        mAuth.signOut();
        Toast.makeText(UploadVideo.this,"Signed Out",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        startActivity(new Intent(UploadVideo.this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }




    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == PICK_VIDEO || resultCode == RESULT_OK || data != null || data.getData() != null){

            videoUri = data.getData();

            vidoeView.setVideoURI(videoUri);
        }
    }

    public void ChooseVideo(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("video/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(intent,PICK_VIDEO);
    }

    private String getExtension(Uri uri){
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        MimeTypeMap mimeTypeMap = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        return mimeTypeMap.getExtensionFromMimeType(contentResolver.getType(uri));
    }

    public void ShowVideo(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(UploadVideo.this, ShowVideoActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void UploadVideo() {
        final String videoName = editText.getText().toString();
        final String search = editText.getText().toString().toLowerCase();

        if(videoUri != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(videoName)){

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            final StorageReference reference = storageReference.child(System.currentTimeMillis() + "." +getExtension(videoUri));
            uploadTask = reference.putFile(videoUri);

            Task<Uri> uriTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                @Override
                public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                    if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                        throw task.getException();
                    }
                    return reference.getDownloadUrl();
                }
            })
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {

                            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                Toast.makeText(UploadVideo.this,"Video Saved",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                member.setName(videoName);
                                member.setVideourl(downloadUri.toString());
                                member.setSearch(search);
                                String i = databaseReference.push().getKey();
                                databaseReference.child(i).setValue(member);
                            }else{
                                Toast.makeText(UploadVideo.this,"Failed to upload",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }); }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(UploadVideo.this,"All fields are required",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code i used for storing and uploading data into database